# Como realizar el conteo de tokens de tipo de String, int, float, char, boolean? en python

Tags: python

Necesito ayuda para poder realizar este ejercicio, ya realicé la parte de la interfaz, me hace falta realizar la parte que al momento de darle clic en el botón de contar token, tiene que leer un archivo `.txt`, leerlo y poner cuántos tokens hay de cada tipo. Espero me puedan ayudar y haya explicado bien.

[image: Interfaz gráfica]

Comment: se entiende mas o menos, quedaría mejor si agregaras el código ^_^

Comment: El código que tengo es solo la parte de la interfaz, la parte que he estado investigando es la del conteo, Siento que no serviría de nada si pongo el código que hice

Comment: Cual es la estructura del txt? Son expresiones de Python separados por espacios?

Answer (score 1):

Una solución que no requiere librerías especializadas:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3.0, 4.0, "cinco", "seis", []]
cuenta = {}
for elemento in lista:
    clase = str(type(elemento)).split("'")[1]
    if clase not in cuenta:
        cuenta[clase] = 1
    else:
        cuenta[clase] += 1
print(cuenta)  # -> {'int': 2, 'float': 2, 'str': 2, 'list': 1}
```

El diccionario `cuenta` tiene por llave la clase del objeto (int, str, list, ...) y por valor el número de veces que aparece.

Recorremos la lista y primero extraemos el tipo del objeto con `type(x)`. Con `str()` obtenemos su representación en caracteres, que sería algo en el formato "<class 'int'>".

Si divido el string en tres partes por el caracter "'" usando

```
str(type(x)).split("'")
```

obtengo una lista cuyo segundo elemento es el nombre de la clase (`int, str, float`, etc.)

Teniendo la clase podemos consultar si está en el diccionario. En tal caso le sumamos uno a su contenido. Si no está, entonces agregamos una entrada al diccionario con cuenta en 1.

#### Edición

Nuestro amigo Dante conoce una forma más corta de obtener el nombre de la clase:

```
clase = type(elemento).__name__
```

En Python todos son objetos de alguna clase, y toda clase tiene un nombre, guardado en `__name__`.

Comment: La respuesta está buena! Solo quería hacer una propuesta: se puede obtener el nombre de una clase con su atributo `__name__`: `type(elemento).__name__`. No digo que sea un defecto, para nada.

Comment: @DanteS. Si, vi el encontrón ese. Bien desagradable el personaje. Tóxico. Lo reportaria, pero me tienen bloqueado.

Comment: Gracias por darme tu opinion c: Me alegro que no haya sido yo el del problema. Eliminaré mi comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de 2 maneras, una con una list comprehension y otra con la librería NLTK

#### List Comprehension

```
lista= (sorted((fichero.txt)))
lista = [(x, lista.count(x)) for x in lista]
```

Te dará la frecuencia de distribución de cada token, es decir, cuántas veces aparece cada palabra. Si después quieres quitar las repetidas, usa  `set(lista)`

#### Con NLTK

```
import nltk
print(list(nltk.FreqDist(fichero.txt).items()))
```

Comment: Hay cosas que debo resaltar en tu respuesta. Primero, fichero.txt es una cadena SOLO si está entre comillas. Sin las comillas Python interpreta fichero.txt como un intento de acceder al atributo txt de la variable fichero. Segundo, incluso corrigiendo eso, 'fichero.txt' es una cadena, NO una lista con todas las lineas del txt.

Comment: Perdona, no era mi intención ofenderte. No me pasé de listo. Solo resalto estas cosas para ayudarte a mejorar tu respuesta. Recuerda que desde mi perspectiva eres un desconocido, no sabía que hacías tutoriales. No me había quedado claro que fichero.txt en realidad representaba el archivo ya leido. Vendría genial que edites tu respuesta y pongas esa aclaración, ya que el OP podría confundirse al igual que yo.

Comment: De paso podrías hacer que tu respuesta sea aun más linda utilizando subtítulos y poniendo en formato de código solo el código (de hecho alguien propuso una edición que hace eso)

Comment: Encuentro inadecuada tu respuesta a @DanteS. Puedes revisar su historial de participación en el sitio y verás que nunca hubo mala intención de su parte.